# Reading used variables from a smarty template file

Tags: php, variables, smarty3

Is there a way to get all used variables from a smarty (3) template file before assigning variables to the smarty object?

For example I have the following template file:

```
Hello {$user.firstname},<br />
You are active in the following groups:<br />
{foreach from=$user.groups item=group}
   - {$group.name}<br />
{/foreach}
<br />
The city you live in is: {$city}
```

Now the reason im asking is because instead of getting all user information I would just like to create a query depending on the used variables in smarty.

Is there anyway to do something like the following:

```
$smarty = new smarty;

$result = $smarty->getVariablesFromTemplate('index.tpl');

print_r($result);

/* outputs:
array(
   'user' => array(
      'firstname' => true,
      'groups' => array(
         'name' => true
      ),
      'city' => true
   )
);
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your `SQL` but you can access template variables assigned to smarty (using `$smarty->assign('var', 'value')`) by following code

```
$tpl_vars = $smarty->_tpl_vars;
```

Comment: The nice way of doing so is actually using `$smarty->getTemplateVars();` however I'm not trying to read what variables I have assigned to the template, im trying to read what variables are used in the template file.

Comment: for that, you'll have to parse the template file I think.